# Relation between nonorientability of the Möbius strip and the Möbius bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

There are two ways in which the open Möbius strip $M$ is related to orientability:

1. $M$ is nonorientable as a manifold;
2. $M$ is the total space of the nonorientable line bundle $M \to S^1$.

Is there any relation between these two concepts? If so, can it be generalized to arbitrary vector bundles?

Is a statement like "A noncompact manifold $M$ is nonorientable iff it is the total space of a nonorientable vector bundle" unreasonable?

Comment: The total space of a vector bundle (of positive dimension) is never compact, and there are many compact nonorientable manifolds, e.g. $\mathbb{RP}^2$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Right. What if we consider only noncompact manifolds?

Comment: The last statement is unreasonable for two reasons.  First, if the base manifold is non-orientable, then then a non-orientable vector bundle over it is orientable as a manifold.  Second, even if you have a non-orientable vector bundle over an orientable manifold, if you puncture it, there is no reason for it to now be the total space of a non-orientable vector bundle at all, yet it will still be non-orientable as a manifold.

Comment: Jason's first point bears repeating. In particular, the total space of any tangent bundle is always orientable.

Comment: What about ${\bf RP}^2\times \bf R$ ? If it was a vector bundle over something this something would be a surface. By computing the fundamental group (or the $H_1$) this surface would be ${\bf RP}^2$, but the only non-orientable vector bundle over the projective plane is the orientation bundle which is orientable as a manifold.